# How to parse a line and result in array - stuck

Tags: php, regex, arrays, preg-match

Here's what I try to do :

```
isNumeric(right(trim(contract_id),1))

isNumeric
    right
        trim
            contract_id
        1

isNumeric(right(trim(contract_id),1), bob, george(five(four, two)))

isNumeric
    right
        trim
            contract_id
        1
    bob
    george
        five
            four
            two
```

So basiclly it take a line (let'say trim(var)) and will make an array of it (array(trim => array(var)).

I did try with regex and strpos but no result... I need help. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: chris nailed it.  This problem is more complicated than can be done with a (sane) regular expression.  Regular expressions might be *part* of your solution but they won't be the whole of it.  A pure regex solution would very much be a "now you have two problems" scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off a descent parser will always give you better control.
A whole regex solution might enable you to skip errors or at least let you continue
and not crap out.

Your format is extremely simple, and an engine that can do internal recursion could at
least get you an outter match. Using language recursion, you could re-enter that regex
enabling you to parse the core.

I'm no php expert, but if it supports regex recursion and language level *eval()* you
will be able to inject an array construct into the source text.
Then eval the string to create an nested array image, complete with parameters.

I actually converted your text to an array in about 12 lines of Perl, but added to
it when it got interresting.

Here is a Perl sample. Its dumbed down so its readable. It might give you some inspiration to try it in php (if it can do these things). Like I said I'm no php expert.

```
  use Data::Dumper;

  my $str = '
    asdf("asg")
    isNumeric(right(trim(contract_id),1))
    var = \'aqfbasdn\'
    isNumeric(right(trim ( ,contract_id,),-1, j( ) ,"  ", bob, george(five(four, two))))
  ';

  my $func      = '\w+';           # Allowed characters (very watered down)
  my $const     = '[\w*&^+-]+';
  my $wspconst  = '[\w*&^+\s-]+';

  my $GetRx = qr~
    \s*
    (                       # 1 Recursion group
       (?:
           \s* ($func) \s* 
           [(]
              (?:  (?> (?: (?!\s*$func\s*[(] | [)] ) . )+ ) 
                 | (?1)                                         
              )*                                               
           [)]
       )
     )                                                 
  ~xs;

  my $ParseRx = qr~
    (                        # 1 Recursion group
       (?:
           \s* ($func) \s*                                    # 2 Function name
           [(]
           (                                                  # 3 Function core
              (?:  (?> (?: (?!\s*$func\s*[(] | [)] ) . )+ ) 
                 | (?1)                                         
              )*                                               
           )                                                   
           [)]
                                         # OR..other stuff
                                         # Note that this block of |'s is where               
                                         # to put code to parse constants, strings,
                                         # delimeters, etc ... Not much done, but
                                         # here is where that goes.
                                         # -----------------------------------------
         |  \s*["'] ($wspconst) ["']\s*      # 4,5 Variable constants
         | \s* ($const) \s* 
                                         # Lastly, accept empty parameters, if
         | (?<=,)                        # a comma behind us,
         | (?<=^)(?!\s*$)                # or beginning of a new 'core' if actually a paramater.
       )       
     )                                                 
  ~xs;

##
  print "Source string:\n$str\n";
  print "=======================================\n";
  print "Searching string for functions ...\n";
  print "=======================================\n\n";


  while ($str =~ /$GetRx/g) {
      print "------------------\nParsing:\n$1\n\n";
      my $res = parse_func($1);
      print "String to be eval()'ed:\n$res\n\n";

      my $hashref = eval $res.";";
      print "Hash from eval()'ed string:\n", Dumper( $hashref ), "\n\n";
  }

###
  sub parse_func
  {
      my ($core) = @_;
      $core =~ s/$ParseRx/ parse_callback($2, $3, "$4$5") /eg;
      return $core;
  }

  sub parse_callback
  {
      my ($fname, $fbody, $fconst) = @_;
      if (defined $fbody) {
          return "{'$fname'=>[" . (parse_func( $fbody )) . "]}";
      }
      return "'$fconst'"
  }
```

Output

```
Source string:

    asdf("asg")
    isNumeric(right(trim(contract_id),1))
    var = 'aqfbasdn'
    isNumeric(right(trim ( ,contract_id,),-1, j( ) ,"  ", bob, george(five(four, two))))

=======================================
Searching string for functions ...
=======================================

------------------
Parsing:
asdf("asg")

String to be eval()'ed:
{'asdf'=>['asg']}

Hash from eval()'ed string:
$VAR1 = {
          'asdf' => [
                      'asg'
                    ]
        };


------------------
Parsing:
isNumeric(right(trim(contract_id),1))

String to be eval()'ed:
{'isNumeric'=>[{'right'=>[{'trim'=>['contract_id']},'1']}]}

Hash from eval()'ed string:
$VAR1 = {
          'isNumeric' => [
                           {
                             'right' => [
                                          {
                                            'trim' => [
                                                        'contract_id'
                                                      ]
                                          },
                                          '1'
                                        ]
                           }
                         ]
        };


------------------
Parsing:
isNumeric(right(trim ( ,contract_id,),-1, j( ) ,"  ", bob, george(five(four, two))))

String to be eval()'ed:
{'isNumeric'=>[{'right'=>[{'trim'=>['' ,'contract_id','']},'-1',{'j'=>[ ]} ,'  ','bob',{'george'=>[{'five'=>['four','two']}]}]}]}

Hash from eval()'ed string:
$VAR1 = {
          'isNumeric' => [
                           {
                             'right' => [
                                          {
                                            'trim' => [
                                                        '',
                                                        'contract_id',
                                                        ''
                                                      ]
                                          },
                                          '-1',
                                          {
                                            'j' => []
                                          },
                                          '  ',
                                          'bob',
                                          {
                                            'george' => [
                                                          {
                                                            'five' => [
                                                                        'four',
                                                                        'two'
                                                                      ]
                                                          }
                                                        ]
                                          }
                                        ]
                           }
                         ]
        };
```

Comment: This solution is genius. However, I could make it work but not at 100%. Here's my PHP code I did : http://pastebin.com/yp6f6vkJ . Here's the result of the code : `'isNumeric'('right'({'trim'=>['contract_id']},'1'))`. Something is cleary wrong with my code.

Comment: Nevermind my last message. I was missing a space in the regex. Here's the working code : http://pastebin.com/0HaNHvfC

Thanks, god of regex.

Comment: @David Bélanger - Great, it works in php. I tried to run you code at ideone but thier php doesn't support jason_decode(). So, I modded it to embed `func'=>Array()` and used `eval()`. Seems to work. Here is the code http://ideone.com/0aKQW . One thing I did notice is that the regex's should use the `//s` modifier though on these `'/'.$GetRx.'/s'` and `'/'.$ParseRx.'/s'`. Glad it works!

Comment: The eval thing is working also, but this ain't a good thing to use. A user could inject code in here. If I understand correct, I need to add s add the end of the regex ?

Comment: Your right, thats a possibility with eval. Yes, you should add the 's' like the one I highlighted. There are a dot '.' metachar in the regex's bodies.